# Buffer table in a database, Good or not?

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

I have a question !

I need to make a university project, and in this project i will have one database table like this :

[image]

This table will have a LOT of records !!!!!!
And for manage this i need to create a validation system.

What is the best (and why) between create a buffer table like this :

[image]

Or add a column in my table like this :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: How many rows does "*a LOT of records !!!!!!*" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not have enough information to provide a real answer.  Here is some guidance on how to think about the situation.  Which approach depends on the nature of your application and especially on what "validation" means.

One reasonable interpretation is that "validation" is part of a work-flow process, so it happens only once (or 99% of the time only once).  And, you never want to see unvalidated advertisements when you look look at advertisements.  If this is the case, then there would typically be additional information about the validation process.

This scenario suggests two reasonable approaches:

- Do the validation inside a transaction.  This would be reasonable if the validation process were entirely in the database and was measured in seconds.
- Have a separate table for advertisements being validated.  Perhaps even a separate table per "user" or "entity" responsible for them.  Depending on the nature of the validation process, this could be a queue that feeds them to people doing the validation.

Putting them in the "advertisements" table doesn't make sense, because there is likely to be additional information involved with the validation process -- who, what, where, when, how.

If an advertisement can be validated and invalidated multiple times, then the best approach may be to put them in the same table.  Once again, there are questions about the nature of the process.

Getting access to the two groups without a full table scan is tricky.  If 10% of the rows are invalidated and 90% are validated, then a normal index would require a full table scan for reading either group.  To get faster access to the smaller group, here are two options:

- clustered index on the validation flag.
- separate partitions for validated and invalidated rows.

In both cases, changing the validation flag for a record is relatively expensive, because it involves reading and writing the record on different data pages.  Unless dozens of changes are made per second, this is probably not a big deal.

Comment: Instead of partitioning he can create an index with valid as the leading column to gain 100% scanning efficiency. Partitioning seems like a nuclear option here. None of the usual features such as dropping partitions or different storage are likely to be very useful.

Comment: +1 This is actually the *correct* way to think about things. @usr Whether or not it is practical may depend on a few external factors -- if validation is actually part of a real workflow that is going to be implemented anyway, then there is no reason to not do things this way This is what I was hinting at in my answer that it might make coding more complex -- but if you require a workflow in the application code then this is already going to be the case.

Comment: Yeah, if the workflow requires it that's certainly a plus but it does not force the issue. Having a single table for all states of the workflow can be very convenient. After all, whether the "items" are "validated" or not does not change the identity of the item. It's merely a different state. Example: If an order can be in 10 states you would not open 10 tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !!!
Actually, the process of validation will happens once.
And if a advertisement is not validate, it will be destroy.

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Here, there is no need to have a separate "buffer table". You can just properly index the `valid` field. So the following index would essentially automatically create a buffer table:

```
create unique index x on y (id)
  include (all columns)
  where (valid = 0)
```

This index creates a copy of the yet invalid data. You can do lots of variations such as

```
create unique index x on y (valid, id)
```

There's really no need for a separate table. Indexes are very easy compared to partitioning or even manually partitioning. Much less work, more general, more flexible and less potential for human error.

Comment: Whether or not this is reasonable is entirely dependent on the database used -- not all db systems handle indexes as smoothly as others, particularly on complex queries where an insufficiently intelligent query planner may discard the index and run a sequential scan over the whole table, either due to an intermediate sort that confuses it or just poorly tuned cost estimates .

Comment: True. Without thinking about it I kind of assumed SQL Server. But this scenario is really simple, so I'm not sure what problems could arise. Your examples are valid in principle but I find them rather unlikely. Indexing on a single and apparently selective column seems like the simplest possible thing.

Answer (score 0):

Either approach is valid, and which will perform better will depend more on the type of database you are using rather than the theoretical question of whether it is more correct to use a boolean or partition this into two tables.

I actually prefer the partitioning approach (your buffer table idea), but *it will be more complex to code around*. This may be a significant point to consider. *Most* modern databases will handle the boolean criteria very well with an index, but sometimes you can be surprised.

The most important thing from a development perspective right now is to pick one and run with it instead of paralyzing your project while you decide the "right" one.